# What are the applications of the depth 2 reduction to the subfactors theory?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $(N \subset M)$ be an irreducible finite depth ($>2$) finite index unital inclusion of hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factors, then for $n$ sufficiently large the subfactor $(N \subset M_n)$ is depth $2$ (*reducible*) and is isomorphic to $(R^H \subset R)$ with $H$ a weak Kac algebra (also called quantum groupoid, see prop. 9.1.1 p37 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006057v2)).  Then the initial subfactor is isomorphic to an intermediate of $(R^H \subset R)$ and by Galois correspondence  (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001020)), it is completely given by the inclusion $(J \subset H)$ with $J$ a left coideal subalgebra of $H$.

*Question*: what are the applications of this result to the subfactors theory?
(In what this help to better understand the subfactors?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Two answers of Dmitri Nikshych:*

> **Dmitri**
>   This reduces the study of subfactors to that of weak Hopf algebras.
>   Equivalently (and more importantly)  it relates the theory of finite
>   index finite depth subfactors to the theory of fusion categories and
>   module categories over them.
>
> There are many papers by Snyder, Morrison and others in this
>   direction.
>
> A concrete example: it follows from the theory of fusion categories
>   that the index of a subfactor is a cyclotomic integer.

**Sebastien**
Yes the fusion category framework helps a lot!

My question is more about the weak Kac algebra framework.
An irreducible finite index finite depth subfactor is completely given by an inclusion of a left coideal subalgebra in a weak Kac algebra,
i.e. an inclusion of finite dimensional ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebras with an additional "quantum group"-like structure.
In what this help to better understand the subfactors?

> **Dmitri**
>   To me weak Hopf algebras are a bridge between subfactors and fusion
>   categories.
>
> The importance of weak Hopf algebra description of finite depth
>   subfactors is that  it reduces a seemingly analytic problem (inclusion
>   of von Neumann algebras)  to purely algebraic theory.  It also folows
>   that weak Hopf algebras are the correct  symmetries of subfactors just
>   like groups are symmetries of field extensions.